# JSR223 PreProcessor generates invalid format using Groovy in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, preprocessor

My Groovy script looks like

```
def statuses = []
def item = []
def items = []
def payload = []

1.upto(1, { index ->
    def data = new File('/Users/my/Desktop/items.csv').readLines().get(index).split(',')
    def a = [:]
        a.put('1', 5)
    a.put('2', 4)
    statuses.add(a)
    def attr = [:]
    attr.put('3', data[3].toInteger())
    def attributes = [:]
    attributes.put('4', statuses)
    attributes.put('5', attr)
    item.add(attributes)
})

1.upto(1, { index ->
    def data = new File('/Users/my/Desktop/locations.csv').readLines().get(index).split(',')
    def attr = [:]
    attr.put('6', item)
    attr.put('7', data[1].toInteger())
    items.add(attr)
    def attributes = [:]
    attributes.put('param', items)
    payload.add(attributes)

})

def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload)

sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",json.toPrettyString(),"")
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

Result is payload for my http request

```
[
    {
        "param": [
            {
                "6": [
                    {
                        "4": [
                            {
                                "1": 5,
                                "2": 4
                            }
                        ],
                        "5": {
                            "3": 101
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "7": 20
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The problem is when I prepare JsonBuilder(payload), def payload is array (def payload = [])
As result I have those format of nesting

```
[
    {
        "param"
```

What should I do, to make my payload nesting without [] bracers? Like this:

```
{
   "param"
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `def payload = [:]`
2. `payload.put('param', your_request_body)`

You need to use a [LazyMap](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/apache/groovy/json/internal/LazyMap.html) in order to generate a JSON Object, not a JSON Array.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)